# Tokens not received after redirecting to dashboard in an Angular application using AWS Cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am working in AWS-cognito with angular application, in that I have not received tokens after redirecting to my dashboard.

In LoginComponent.html file :

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLoginClick()">Login</button>
```

In main.ts file :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const oauth = {
  // Domain name
  domain: 'finity-web.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',

  // Authorized scopes
  scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
  responseType: 'code',
    AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: false
  },
  // urlOpener: urlOpener
}
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
      oauth: oauth
  },
});

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

In LoginComponent.ts file :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoginClick(){
    const URL="https://finity-web.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/signup?response_type=code&client_id=2770pio4plmettraat9ctdmkng&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200"; 
    window.open(URL);
    console.log(URL);
  }

}
```

I am new to AWS. Please help me solving this problem. Any suitable solution is highly appreciated.